# php mysql search row with multiple arrays in cells

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

ok, so stay with me here ...

i have a site with a table of about 80,000 rows; i am trying to search this table with one MySQL query. The problem is that each of the fields in the row i'm searching has / might have an array (ex: year = 2017,2016,2015, etc), and some of them may not have anything at all. i have tried doing a loop through to and build my "WHERE" clause as i pull the results, but that isn't working either.

any thoughts? any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

CODE:

INSERT INTO the table - this is one of the 13 different rows

```
if(!empty($_POST['pd_year']) && is_array($_POST['pd_year'])) {

    $pd_year = implode(",", $_POST['pd_year']);

        $insert_year = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE prod_desigs_search_test SET pds_year = '$pd_year' WHERE s_id = '$search'"); 

} elseif(empty($_POST['pd_year'])) {

    $insert_year = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE prod_desigs_search_test SET pds_year = ' ' WHERE s_id = '$search'"); 

}
```

SELECT THE design and check if it is an array or not:

```
$get_search = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prod_desigs_search_test WHERE s_id = '$s_id'"); 
while($new_search = mysqli_fetch_array($get_search)) {

$pd_year_ex = $new_search['pds_year'];

if(!empty($pd_year_ex) && is_array($pd_year_ex)) {
    $pd_year = explode(",", $pd_year_ex, 0);
    $year = $pd_year[0];
} elseif(!empty($pd_year_ex) && !is_array($pd_year_ex)) {
    $year = $pd_year_ex;
} 

$search = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM prod_designs WHERE pd_year = '$year'");
while($row_search = mysqli_fetch_array($search)) {
```

EDIT

I have tried to build out the "WHERE" in the query dependent on the `is_array` check like this:

```
$where = "WHERE ";

if(!empty($pd_year_ex) && is_array($pd_year_ex)) {
    $pd_y = $pd_year[0];
    foreach ($pd_y as $year) {
        $where .= "pd_year LIKE '%".$year."%'";
    }
} elseif(!empty($pd_year_ex) && !is_array($pd_year_ex)) {
    $where .= "pd_year LIKE '%".$pd_year_ex."%'";
} elseif(empty($pd_year_ex)) {
    $where .= "";
}
```

and this doesn't seem to be working either. i am just trying to understand how to do a search like this:

```
$search = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM designs WHERE pd_year LIKE '%2017,2016,2015%'")(etc)
```

I know it won't go with the above, but how do i search a table for something like this?

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() ?

Comment: By array, do you mean that it's a VarChar field that has comma separated values? If so, all you need is a LIKE in the search.

Comment: @itsols ... yes it is a varchar field that has comma separated values. do i still need to explode the array? or skip the checking to see if it is an array or not?

Comment: Consider not having arrays, or not bothering with an RDBMS.

Comment: @AndrewFerguson your requirement is a little vague. First tell me this... Is the POST array a single value (eg: 2016) or does it contain multiple values (eg: 2016,2017...)? And are you only trying to see if this is within the field pd_year?

Comment: @itsols ... it can contain both ... the form that the row is created from can be a single or multiple entries; that's why i have the check to see if it's an array or not ... does that make sense? i'm sorry ... i messed up the wording when i first asked the question